# SQL: how to find maximum value items according a attribute

Tags: sql

I am a beginner of SQL, having this table instructor:

```
ID     name   dept_name   salary
001     A       d01        1000
002     B       d02        2000
003     C       d01        3000
...
```

I am writing a code to find people who have highest salary in each department like:

```
name      dept_name
 C           d01
 B           d02
```

I do know how to find maximum value 
but I have no idea how to use it by according dept_name for all each department.

Comment: Note your table is not fully normalized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will ensure that only records which are the highest salary for each department are returned to the result set.

```
SELECT name, dept_name, salary
FROM tbl t
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT salary FROM tbl t2 WHERE t2.salary>t.salary AND t2.dept_name=t.dept_name)
```

Using `SELECT name, MAX(salary)` like other answerers have used won't work. Using `MAX()` will return the highest salary for each department, but the name will not necessarily be related to that salary value.

For example, `SELECT MIN(salary), MAX(salary)` is most likely going to pull values from different records. That's how aggregate functions work.

Answer (score 1):

```
select name,   max(dept_name)
from tbl
group by name
```

Comment: why are you selecting the max(dept_name)?

Comment: you can use aggregate functions for any others fields

Answer (score 0):

You can use the group by clause.  Check this [w3Schools link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

```
SELECT NAME,DEPT_NAME,max(SALARY) FROM table_name group by DEPT_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume it is a requirement to not include the salary in the result:

```
WITH INSTRUCTOR
     AS
     (
      SELECT * 
        FROM (
              VALUES ('001', 'A', 'd01', 1000),
                     ('002', 'B', 'd02', 2000), 
                     ('003', 'C', 'd01', 3000)
             ) AS T (ID, name, dept_name, salary)
     ), 
     INSTRUCTOR_DEPT_HIGHEST_SALARY
     AS 
     (
      SELECT dept_name, MAX(salary) AS highest_salary
        FROM INSTRUCTOR
       GROUP 
          BY dept_name
     )
SELECT ID, name, dept_name
  FROM INSTRUCTOR AS T
 WHERE EXISTS (
               SELECT * 
                 FROM INSTRUCTOR_DEPT_HIGHEST_SALARY AS H
                WHERE H.dept_name = T.dept_name
                      AND H.salary = T.highest_salary
              );
```