# Displaying last_name, Dept_id, (max)Salary

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I am using iSQL*Plus.

I want to display the (last_name, department_id, salary) of employees, who is earning the highest salary from every departments with the help of an SQL statement.

Consider Table name as emp

```
select department_id, max(salary)
from empl
group by department_id
```

This will return department_id wise max salary.

But now I want to display the name of those employees who are getting this max(salary) in their respective department.

Comment: We'll need a sample query and/or table names for a start.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9599299/sql-how-to-find-maximum-value-items-according-a-attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH RCounter AS (
    SELECT department_id, last_Name, Salary,
           DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY department_id ORDER BY Salary DESC) AS RowNumberCounter
        FROM <<tablename>>
)
SELECT department_id, last_Name, Salary
    FROM RCounter 
    WHERE RowNumberCounter = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This was the query I had. have figured out a solution for the same.

Qstn:

I want to display the (last_name, department_id, salary) of employees, who is earning the highest salary from every departments with the help of an SQL statement.

Soln:

Select last_name, salary, department_id
From employees e
Where salary in (select max(salary) from employees where department_id= e.department_id);

Best regards,
Kuntal Roy